# Creating combination of sequences

Tags: r

I am trying to solve following problem:

Consider 5 simple sequences: 0:100, 100:0, rep(0,101), rep(50,101), rep(100,101)

I need sets of 3 numeric variables, which have above sequences in all combinations. Since there are 5 sequences and 3 variables, there can be 5*5*5 combinations, hence total of 12625 (5*5*5*101) numbers in each variable (101 for each sequence).

These can be grouped in a data.frame of 12625 rows and 4 columns. First column (V) will simply have seq(1:12625) (rownumbers can be used in its place). Other 3 columns (A,B,C) will have above 5 sequences in different combinations. For example, the first 101 rows will have 0:100 in all 3 A,B and C. Next 101 rows will have 0:100 in A and B, and 100:0 in C. And so on...

I can create sequences as:

```
s = list()
s[[1]] = 0:100
s[[2]] = 100:0
s[[3]] = rep(0,101)
s[[4]] = rep(50,101)
s[[5]] = rep(100,101)
```

But how to proceed further? I do not really need the data frame but I need a function that returns a list containing the values of c(A,B,C) for the number (first or V column) sent to it. The number can obviously vary from 1 to 12625.

How can I create such a function. I will prefer a vector solution or one using apply family functions to optimize the speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked for a vectorized solution, so here's one using only `data.table` (similar to @SimonGs methodology)

```
library(data.table)
grd <- CJ(A = seq_len(5), B = seq_len(5), C = seq_len(5))
res <- grd[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(s[x]))]
res
#          A   B   C
#     1:   0   0   0
#     2:   1   1   1
#     3:   2   2   2
#     4:   3   3   3
#     5:   4   4   4
#  ---            
# 12621: 100 100 100
# 12622: 100 100 100
# 12623: 100 100 100
# 12624: 100 100 100
# 12625: 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with two solutions. I find this hard to do with `apply` and the likes since they tend to give an output that is not so nice to handle (maybe someone can "tame" them better than I can :D)

First solution uses seperate calls to `lapply`, second one uses a `for` loop and some programming No-No's. Personally I prefer the second one, first one is faster though...

```
grd <- expand.grid(a=1:5,b=1:5,c=1:5)

# apply-ish
A <- lapply(grd[,1], function(z){ s[[z]] })
B <- lapply(grd[,2], function(z){ s[[z]] })
C <- lapply(grd[,3], function(z){ s[[z]] })
dfr <- data.frame(A=do.call(c,A), B=do.call(c,B), C=do.call(c,C))

# for-ish
mat <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(grd)){
 cur <- grd[i,]
 tmp <- cbind(s[[cur[,1]]],s[[cur[,2]]],s[[cur[,3]]])
 mat <- rbind(mat,tmp)
}
```

The output of both `dfr` and `mat` seem to be what you describe.

Cheers!