# R - generate unique sequences of list with reoccuring items

Tags: r, sequence, permutation

I wish to generate the unique sequences of elements in a list where some elements are not unique in R

```
sequence <- c(1,0,1,0)
```

e.g:

```
result<-function(sequence)  
result:
  seq1 seq2 seq3 seq4 seq5 seq6
1    1    1    0    0    0    1
2    0    1    0    1    1    0
3    1    0    1    0    1    0
4    0    0    1    1    0    1
```

notice that all sequences contain every element from the original sequence,
such that the sum of the sequence is always 2

gtools returns "too few different elements"

```
result <- gtools::permutations(4, 4, coseq)
```

I am not finding any SO post that directly solve this, but instead allow element repeats:[Creating combination of sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713005/creating-combination-of-sequences)
achievable with `expand.grid` and different lengths of sequences.

**EDIT:**
The above is a minimal example, ideally it would work on the sequence:

```
 sequence = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

It is somewhat important that the solution does not generate duplicates that are then subsequently removed, since a longer sequence, say 20 or 30 will be very computationally demanding if duplicates are generated.

Comment: Did you see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38485052/8583393

Comment: Thanks - thats exactly it and that solution is less computationally demanding, unlike the answers below, which work on short sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of packages specifically built for this.

First the `arrangements` package:

```
## sequence is a bad name as it is a base R function so we use s instead
s <- c(1,0,1,0)
arrangements::permutations(unique(s), length(s), freq = table(s))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1
```

Next, we have `RcppAlgos` (I am the author):

```
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(unique(s), length(s), freqs = table(s))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1
```

They are both very efficient as well. To give you an idea, for the actual need by the OP, the other methods will fail (I think there is a limit on the number of rows for a matrix ... 2^31 - 1, not sure though) or take a very long time as they will have to generate `16! ~= 2.092e+13` permutations before any further processing. However, with these two packages, the return is instant:

```
## actual example needed by OP
sBig <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)

system.time(a <- arrangements::permutations(unique(sBig), length(sBig), freq = table(sBig)))
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.001   0.002 

system.time(b <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(unique(sBig), length(sBig), freqs = table(sBig)))
user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.001   0.002 

identical(a, b)
[1] TRUE

dim(a)
[1] 11440    16
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m = apply(gtools::permutations(2, 4, 1:4, repeats.allowed = TRUE), 1, function(x) sequence[x])
m[,colSums(m) == 2]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    1    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned `gtools::permutations`, you could do this

First generate all permutations

```
m <- apply(permutations(4, 4, 1:length(sequence)), 1, function(x) sequence[x])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     1
#[2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    1     1     0     0     1     1
#[3,]    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1     0     1     1     0     0
#[4,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0     1     1     1     0     0
#     [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24]
#[1,]     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#[2,]     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1
#[3,]     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0
#[4,]     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1
```

Then remove duplicate columns (from the indistinguishability of the 1's and 0's)

```
m[, !duplicated(apply(m, 2, paste, collapse = ""))]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    1    0    1
#[4,]    0    1    0    0    1    1
```